# How to post an image in a twitter account, using oauth in iOS?

Tags: ios, image, post, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have managed to receive the twitter oauth data as below (after the user logs in), and as much as I have searched I haven't found a way that works fine  to **post an image** in the twitter profile of the user. Is there any detailed tutorial?

```
  oauth_token=xxxxxxxxjU8gs6&oauth_token_secret=xxxxD7ITa&user_id=xxx73&screen_name=manostijeras&oauth_verifier=xx07
```

Thanks

PS: I used this tutorial to receive twitter oauth data
http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the procedure->

```
OAToken *token = [[OAToken alloc] initWithKey:OauthAccessToken secret:OauthAccessSecrateKey]; //Set user Oauth access token and secrate key
OAConsumer *consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:ConsumerToken secret:ConsumerSecrateKey]; // Application cosumer token and secrate key

// Url for upload pictures
NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json];

OAMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:finalURL
                                                                   consumer:consumer
                                                                      token:token
                                                                      realm: nil
                                                          signatureProvider:nil];

[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setTimeoutInterval:120];
[theRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];

// Set headers for client information, for tracking purposes at Twitter.(This is optional)
[theRequest setValue:@"TestIphone" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Twitter-Client"];
[theRequest setValue:@"1.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Twitter-Client-Version"];
[theRequest setValue:@"http://www.TestIphone.com/" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Twitter-Client-URL"];

NSString *boundary = @"--Hi all, First Share"; // example taken and implemented.
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[theRequest setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"status\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"latest upload"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media[]\"; filename=\"vizllx_pic1.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"vizllx_pic.png"], 0.5)]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[theRequest prepare];

NSString *oAuthHeader = [theRequest valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:body];

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest
                                             returningResponse:&response                            
                                                         error:&error];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData                                
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but this is not what I am looking for. The app I am building can't use the twitter account that is stored in the settings. Instead, the user is prompted to log in and authorize the app. Then I receive the oauth data and after this I want to post an image to the user's profile

Comment: Thanks. I'll check now

Comment: @user2879002- accept the answer mate , so that it can be helpful for other users.

Comment: Does anyone know, if it is possible to post a video instead of an image? As I've seen in some answers you cannot. It could be only through twitvid. Is it true?

Thanks